# Is there a way to make a camera follow a different GameObject in game? c# 2d

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I already have the unity default camera following the player. But I want it to switch between one character and another, depending on whichever one I have activated. So far all I have is...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;
public Transform player2;

void Update () 
{
    transform.position = new Vector3 (player.position.x + .5f, player.position.y + .55f, -7.2f);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    //switch to player2
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this or something I should focus on learning to do just that or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM I got it. Thanks to Xying for getting me started on the code it was vital. Here's the code now.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;
public Transform player2;
private bool idleFollow = true;
private bool mountFollow = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (!mountFollow && idleFollow && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        mountFollow = true;
        idleFollow = false;
        return;
    }

    if (mountFollow && !idleFollow && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        idleFollow = true;
        mountFollow = false;
        return;
    }

    if (idleFollow && !mountFollow) 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player.position.x + .5f, player.position.y + .55f, -7.2f);
    }

    if (mountFollow && !idleFollow)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (player2.position.x + .5f, player2.position.y + .55f, -7.2f);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems your code can't compile because the `if` statement is outside any block where it can be executed. Check your parentheses carefully and indent your code accordingly.

To achieve what you want, do the following. Add an `else` block, move your current follow code there, and add the follow code for the other object in the already existing `if` block:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    transform.position = new Vector3(player2.position.x + .5f, player2.position.y + .55f, -7.2f);
}
else {
    transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x + .5f, player.position.y + .55f, -7.2f);
}
```

Make sure to get all of the above code in the `Update` method.

You might also want to consider getting rid of magic numbers such as `.5f`, `.55f`, and `-7.2f`, and replace them with well named variables. For example, `var offset = new Vector3(.5f, .55f, -7.2f)` might be fine.

As a general suggestion, it would help to first improve your programming skills in general. I suspect learning while creating a game is a good way to stay motivated, but at the same time, you're going to run into problems like this that could very easily be avoided if you were more familiar with programming in general. There's no wrong way to learn though, so if this feels like a good way for you, go for it!

Comment: o ok. i'll try that after i get home from work. Sorry about that little error btw I didn't originally have that in the script, I was just putting that there as an example of what I was trying to accomplish to make it a bit more clear. I'll definitely not do that again in future questions haha

Comment: Hey sorry i haven't replied in a while. So anyway, that code works only one way. I want you to be able to switch the camera back and forth. As of now it follows one but not the other. When I use the code to switch it back, the camera jumps to its position but doesn't follow it as it moves.

Comment: You need to store which object you're currently following in a field, which you update when the switch key is pressed (or whatever triggers your switch). Then set your position accordingly in the Update method.

Comment: yea. I did that. but what it's doing as a result is that the camera stops following both of them. When I switch the camera between either one, the camera updates its position as if the camera wasn't being updated every frame, but it's in the update function.